# Test interaction with users in R package

Tags: r, readline, r-package, testthat

I am developing an R package and one of the function implements interaction with users through standard input via `readline`.  I now wonder how to test the behavior of this function, preferably with `testthat` library.

It seems `test_that` function assumes the answer is `""` for user-input.  I wish I could test the behavior conditional of various answers users may type in.

Below is a small example code.  In the actual development, the `marryme` function is defined in a separate file and exported to the namespace.
`devtools::test()` gets me an error on the last line because the answer never becomes yes.  I would like to test if the function correctly returns true when user types `"y"`.

```
library(testthat)

test_that("input", {
  marryme <- function() {
    ans <- readline("will you marry me? (y/n) > ")
    return(ans == "y")
  }

  expect_false(marryme())  # this is good
  expect_true(marryme())   # this is no good
})
```

Comment: Split `marryme` into two functions. Put everything except `readline` in a function you can test and call that function with a wrapper function that contains `readline`. Btw., I'm not a fan of using `readline` for user input.

Comment: Thanks, @Roland.  What would you suggest as an alternative for `readline`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Use readLines() with a custom connection

By using `readLines()` instead of `readline()`, you can define the connection, which allows you to customize it using global options.

There are two steps that you need to do:

1. set a default option in your package in `zzz.R` that points to stdin:

   ```
   .onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname){
     options(mypkg.connection = stdin())
   }
   ```
2. In your function, change `readline` to `readLines(n = 1)` and set the connection in `readLines()` to `getOption("mypkg.connection")`

### Example

Based on your MWE:

```r
    library(testthat)

    options(mypkg.connection = stdin())

    marryme <- function() {
      cat("will you marry me? (y/n) > ")
      ans <- readLines(con = getOption("mypkg.connection"), n = 1)
      cat("\n")
      return(ans == "y")
    }

    test_that("input", {

      f <- file()
      options(mypkg.connection = f)
      ans <- paste(c("n", "y"), collapse = "\n") # set this to the number of tests you want to run
      write(ans, f)

      expect_false(marryme())  # this is good
      expect_true(marryme())   # this is no good
      # reset connection
      options(mypkg.connection = stdin())
      # close the file
      close(f)
    })
#> will you marry me? (y/n) > 
#> will you marry me? (y/n) >
```

Comment: This looks good for a single prompt, but I don't immediately see how to extend it to several prompts without having to set a litany of `option`s for each input line...

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I only use two `options()` calls per test suite, no matter how many input lines. The challenge is keeping track of the answer stack (in the `ans` variable).

Comment: I am getting this error like that. `Error in nsenv[[f_name]](dirname(ns_path), package) : 
  unbenutzte Argumente (dirname(ns_path), package)
Ruft auf: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... <Anonymous> -> load_code -> <Anonymous> -> run_pkg_hook`

Comment: I added `libname, pkgname` to the `.onAttach` method. Otherwise it throws the error mentioned in the comments.