# Test user interaction with file.choose()

Tags: r, testthat

I have a function that contains `file.choose()` that I would like to be covered by tests using `testthat` (and in a minor extent using `goodpractices`).

I know such interactive function is not universally loved. I don't adore it myself but in a package I wrote, I really need such helpers for beginner users (with the hope of bringing them to non-interactive alternative).

Is test a way to do it automatically, eg without picking a file manually?

I know [such a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372146/test-interaction-with-users-in-r-package) has (partly) already been asked and I understand the idea behind the answer but I have the feeling that it circumvents my problem rather than solving it. Perhaps, it is, by essence, impossible to tackle.

Below is a code that could help. We would expect no message in the end.

```
library(testthat)

fc <- function(x){
  x <- file.choose()
  return(x)
}

test_that("interactive function works",{
  expect_true(is.character(fc()))
})
```